# Ways to keep .csv format in azure data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am new to Azure and currently trying to design a pipeline where the first step is syncing a local directory (has multiple csvs) with an Azure Container using Azure Data Factory. Problem is Azure keeps changing my .csv files to .txt. Is there a workaround to this? I just need a one to one transfer of the files as is.

I should mention that when I manually upload my csv files to the lake, it's fine. The format change happens when I try to sync the local folder with a self hosted integration runtime.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Azure keeps changing my .csv files to .txt" - are you referring to the output of your Data Factory pipeline? If so, this is a configuration of the pipeline itself. But from the information in your question, it's difficult to tell, as you haven't included any information about the pipeline you created.

Comment: This behavior is controlled in the DataSet for your sink, which could have many options. If you just want whole cloth copy with no transformations, look at using Binary DataSets instead of Delimited. In order to get a more useful answers, as @DavidMakogon said, please provide more information on your current configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we copy the csv file from local folder to Azure Data Lake, we can set the the **File extension: .csv**:

[image]

This option will help you  keep the .csv  file format.

Hope this helps.